# adding a show more/less button in rails 6 and tailwind-CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css

am looking for a way to add a show more/less button with JavaScript, am using tailwind-CSS and rails 6. i haven't setup any JavaScript on my app. if the description is more than 100 words, then it should truncate and show a read more button.

---

```
            <div class="my-4 mx-6 shadow-xl rounded-lg py-4 px-8 border-1 border-gray-400 bg-gray-200">
                <div class="font-medium text-teal-700 capitalize my-3 text-2xl">description</div>
                <div class="font-Arial text-md text-gray-700"><%= @rental.description %> </div>
            </div>
```

---

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: here is the what am trying to achieve

Comment: have a look at alpine js - they have a very basic / similar example on the documentation page. takes 2 minutes to implement.